# Why is 3-chloro-5-(1-methylethenyl)cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-ol named so?

Tags: nomenclature

I'm afraid I can't find an image for this organic compound, but when applying lowest locant rule in the numbering (1-methylethenyl) gets 2 and Cl gets 4. (2,4) is less than (3,5). Why then is lowest locant rule not applied here? Also here (1-methylethenyl) is an alkene, and isn't priority order of alkenes before halogens which have no priority?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important simplified criteria for the numbering are:

1. lower locants for the group that is expressed as suffix
2. lower locants for multiple bonds
3. lower locants for prefixes
4. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

The principal characteristic group of the compound that is given in the question is the $\ce{-OH}$ group. It is expressed as the suffix “-ol”. According to Rule (c), a low locant is assigned first to this group, i.e. “-1-ol”.

In the next step, low locants are assigned to the double bonds according to Rule (e), i.e. “cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-ol”.

That leaves only one possible locant set for the remaining substituents, i.e. “3-chloro” and “5-(prop-1-en-2-yl)”. The rules (f) and (g) are not needed to make a decision.

Therefore, the complete name for the compound that is given in the question is **3-chloro-5-(prop-1-en-2-yl)cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-ol.**

[image: 3-chloro-5-(prop-1-en-2-yl)cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-ol]

Note that the preferred prefix for the “isopropenyl” or “1-methylethenyl” (completely: “1-methyleth-1-en-1-yl”) is now “prop-1-en-2-yl”.